# Creating LSP (Language Server Protocol) for multiple clients using RPC

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

I am trying to create a custom LSP.
My goal is to create one language server for both monaco editor (on web) and vscode extension.

Currently I use Node/IPC to connect the vscode-extension with the server.
and ws-jsonrpc to connect monaco editor with the server.

quoting from this article [Extending a client with the language server protocol](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-the-language-server-protocol-to-extending-a-client-764da0e7863c/)
:

> There are multiple ways to use JSON-RPC, but you see these two ways in
> most implementations:
>
> - Communication is done via the standard input / output, i.e., the command line interface
> - Communication is performed via TCP/IP, i.e., network messages similar to HTTP

I should be able to use JSON-RPC for both communication (internal communication between processes which is the vscode-extesion in my case , and external communication which is monaco-editor in my case)

Here is how I am launching the server for the moment:

For IPC communication:

```
const languageServer = new LanguageServer(createConnection(ProposedFeatures.all));
languageServer.start();
```

For WebSocket RPC:

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as ws from "ws";

import * as rpc from "vscode-ws-jsonrpc";
import * as url from "url";
import * as http from "http";
import * as net from "net";

const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000);
const wss = new ws.Server({
    noServer: true,
    perMessageDeflate: false
});

function launch(socket : rpc.IWebSocket ){
    const reader = new rpc.WebSocketMessageReader(socket);
    const writer = new rpc.WebSocketMessageWriter(socket);
    const languageServer = new LanguageServer(createConnection(reader, writer));
    languageServer.start();
    
}
server.on('upgrade', (request: http.IncomingMessage, socket: net.Socket, head: Buffer) => {
    const pathname = request.url ? url.parse(request.url).pathname : undefined;
    console.log("server on upgrade ", pathname);

    if (pathname === '/sampleServer') {
        wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (webSocket: any) => {

            const socket: rpc.IWebSocket = {
                send: (content: any) => webSocket.send(content, (error: any) => {
                    if (error) {
                        throw error;
                    }
                }),
                onMessage: (cb: any) => webSocket.on('message', cb),
                onError: (cb: any) => webSocket.on('error', cb),
                onClose: (cb: any) => webSocket.on('close', cb),
                dispose: () => webSocket.close()
            };
            // launch the server when the web socket is opened
            if (webSocket.readyState === webSocket.OPEN) {
                launch(socket); 
            } else {
                webSocket.on('open', () => {
                    launch(socket); 
                });
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you read https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide ?

Comment: A server should not operate with "multiple clients using RPC" at the same time. The [protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-16/) specifically states "[t]he protocol currently assumes that one server serves one tool." And I doubt VSCode has hooks to add locking. The code needed for a VSCode extension for your LSP server can be done with only ~100 lines of Typescript, ~100 lines in project.json, and ~10 lines tsconfig.json. You'll have to set it up to use sockets. I use stdin/out, but either is basically the same.

Comment: Yes I know that a server must not operate multiple clients. that's not my question. I am willing to launch multiple servers. but as I understood json-RPC connection can work with socket or stdin. in other words it can expect the two kinds of connection.

Answer (score 0):

The server that you are using should not operate with multiple clients using it at the same time. It even says: "the protocol currently assumes that one server serves one tool.". Also, maybe read this article about your topic. **https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide **